# OnItemSelectedListener not working

Tags: android, database, onclick, spinner

I've follwed some similar question answers to set an onClick listner for the spinner but those responses don't seem to work for me. Maybe I'm doing something work.

I want to update the field hint of an EditText according to what is selected on the spinner.

This is what I've found that should work:

```
public void selectHint() { //Asign function to spinner
    final int[] selectionCurrent = {sel_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()};
    sel_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (selectionCurrent[0] != position){
                updateHint();
            }
            selectionCurrent[0] = position;

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}
```

And just for completeness how I update it, maybe the problem is there:

```
public void updateHint(){ //Decide from db
    int option;
    Cursor res = myDB.getValue(sel_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        res.moveToNext();
        option=res.getInt(0);
        if (option==1) {
            edit_text.setHint(R.string.value1);
        }
        else {
            edit_text.setHint(R.string.value2);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? I don't get any error as a hint.

Comment: R u getting the toast message?

Comment: What is myDB an instance of and have you tried logging the value of option after the option=res.getInt(0); statement? Perhaps it is never 1? Also, what is the purpose of the selectionCurrent[0] = position; statement?

Comment: @NayanSrivastava No, I don't get the Toast message.
Alexi V DatabaseHelper myDB; In other activity I can see that that value can be either 0 or 1 depending on the entry. This is the method:
public Cursor getValue( String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_3 + " FROM "+ TABLE_NAME_1+ " WHERE " +
                COL_2 + " = '"+ name + "'",null);
        return res;
    }
SelectionCurrent was just copied from another question's answer here in stackoverflow, I had to declare it final in order to don't get an error.

Comment: Also I have tried to put a Toast inside both options of the if statement and they don't appear on each selection that I do on the spinner.

Comment: I just checked putting Toast in all updateHint possibilities that it never goes there. And puting an addition button to check if sel_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()); is working properly and getting the name that I want when something is selected and it does work.

So I think the problem is some how in the selectHint method. It doesn't trigger once an option is selected as an onClick method would work. But all similar questions that I've found suggest some code similar to that.